# Search in year ranges odoo

Tags: date, odoo

I have defined these fields:

```
'date_beg': fields.selection([(num, str(num)) for num in range(1900, (datetime.now().year)+1 )], 'Año inicial'),

'date_end': fields.selection([(num, str(num)) for num in range(1900, (datetime.now().year)+1 )], 'Año final'),
```

They generate integer variables in my table:

```
ID          date_beg       date_end

1            1999            2005

2            2000            2004

3            1990            1995
```

My requirement is that when user types a year in search view, odoo will show the records on which this year belongs based on ranges.

For example, If users types '2003' in search view and I have above table values, then odoo will display records with id value 1 & 2.

Please, some suggestions!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the domain you want is like `('date_beg', '<=', 2003), ('date_end', '>=', 2003)`, I guess it would be manageable by modifying the [search view](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/views.html#search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve it like this:

```
def _search_year(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context):
    x = [('cm_datebeg', '<=', args[0][2]), ('cm_dateend', '>=', args[0][2])]
    res = self.search(cr, uid, x, context=context)
    return [('id', 'in', res)]
```

Declared a field like this:

```
       'date_search': fields.function(lambda self: self, string='Búsqueda por año', type='integer', fnct_search=_search_year)
```

Finally, in my search view :

```
                    <field name="date_search"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit the search view of your module or create a new search view using https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#search

```
<field name="date_beg" string="Date Beginning" filter_domain="[('date_beg', '&lt;=', self)]" />
<field name="date_end" string="Date End" filter_domain="[('date_end', '&gt;=', self)]" />
```